# A lower bound for the norm of a convolution

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, fourier-transform, convolution

Let $G:=\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ (the torus group). Suppose that $f\colon G\to[-1,1]$ is a reasonably smooth function such that $\int_G f(z)dz=0$ and $\|\widehat f\|_\infty=1$, and that $g$ is the indicator function of an interval $I:=(-l,l)\subset G$. How small can the norm $\|f\ast g\|_\infty$ of a convolution be with these assumptions?

I am afraid this is a very basic question, but not exactly my cup of tea. I guess the identity $\widehat{f\ast g}=\widehat f\cdot\widehat g$ should be highly relevant, but I cannot see exactly how it helps.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about $g \equiv 1$ and $f(x)=\sin(x)$ (I am working here with periodic functions, which correspond to functions on the torus).

Comment: @PhoemueX: well, good point, but this only means that one cannot give any estimate in the case where all norms $\|g\|_p$ are equal to each other. (BTW, I am actually interested in $g$ being the indicator function of an interval.)

Comment: @PhoemueX: ... in addition, I have modified the question slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any function $h : G \to \mathbb{R}$,
$$\|\hat{h}\|_\infty \leq \|h\|_1.$$
Apply this result to a special function $h$ and use the results you cited above to get a general result.

Comment: This seems to give an upper bound for the infinity norm, while I need a lower bound. Could you explain?

Comment: Sorry, I went the wrong way. Theoretically your lower bound could be 0 because you could have $g$ equal to 1, as an above comment stated. I'm a bit confused by the notation now that I look at it more: how are you defining the Fourier transform on the torus? Generally you use the orthogonal basis $\{e^{\pi i n x}:n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and define Fourier coefficients as $\hat{f}(n) = \langle f, e^{\pi i n \cdot}\rangle$. (This is as $\mathbb{Z}$ is the dual of the torus.) However, what does $\|\hat{f}\|_\infty$ mean?

Comment: If you're defining $\|\hat{f}\|_\infty$ to be $\sup_{n \in \Z} |\hat{f}(n)|$, you could write $f$ as its Fourier series and explicitly carry out the integration, but you don't get a very tractable expression to work with. Consider $f(x) = e^{\pi n i x}, n \neq 0$ Let $g(x) = 1_{(-l,l)}(x).$ We see that $$(f*g)(x) = \int_{x-l}^{x+l}e^{\pi n i y}dy = e^{\pi n i x}\frac{2\sin(\pi n l)}{\pi n i}.$$ So we see that for this specific $f$, $\|f*g\|_\infty = \frac{2\sin(\pi n l)}{\pi n i}$. The sine makes everything more annoying since $\pi n l, n \in \Z$ is dense in the torus if $\pi l$ is irrational

Comment: You are right, I should think over more carefully exactly what I need. Thanks for your comments, anyway.